# Rails 3: Create and Delete action gives 'Template not found' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, blogs

I've come across a really strange error. I've installed '[Blogit](https://github.com/KatanaCode/blogit)' and am trying to add on a few bits and pieces. I'm encountering a strange error when I submit a new entry:

```
Template is missing

Missing template blogit/posts/create, blogit/application/create, application/create with 
{:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * 
"/Users/James/Documents/Websites/Backpack Bug/app/views" * "/Users/James/.rvm/gems/ruby-
1.9.3-p0/gems/blogit-0.4.8/app/views" * "/Users/James/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-
p0/gems/kaminari-0.14.1/app/views" * "/Users/James/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/devise-
2.1.2/app/views"
```

I have a feeling this is to do with my routing. Here is routes.rb

```
appname::Application.routes.draw do

root :to => 'locations#index'

devise_for :users


resources :locations do
   collection do
   get 'location'
  end
end

mount Blogit::Engine => "/blog", :as => "blog" 

end
```

Here is the posts controller:

```
module Blogit

class PostsController < ApplicationController

unless blogit_conf.include_admin_actions
  before_filter :raise_404, except: [:index, :show, :tagged]
end

blogit_authenticate(except: [:index, :show, :tagged])

blogit_cacher(:index, :show, :tagged)
blogit_sweeper(:create, :update, :destroy)

def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.xml {
      @posts = Post.order('created_at DESC')
    }
    format.html {
      @posts = Post.for_index(params[:page])
    }
    format.rss {
      @posts = Post.order('created_at DESC')
    }
  end
end

def show
  @post    = Post.find(params[:id])
  @comment = @post.comments.new
end

def tagged
  @posts = Post.for_index(params[:page]).tagged_with(params[:tag])
  render :index
end

def location
  @georesult = Geocoder.search(params[:location])

 respond_to do |format|
  format.html {render :layout=>false}# venues.html.erb
 end
end

def new
  @post = current_blogger.blog_posts.new(params[:post])
  @location = @post.locations.build
end

def edit
  @post = current_blogger.blog_posts.find(params[:id])
  @location = @post.locations.new
end

def create
  @post = current_blogger.blog_posts.new(params[:post])

respond_to do |format|
  if @post.save
    format.html { redirect_to @post, :method => :get, notice: 'Blog post was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @post, status: :created, location: @post }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end



end

def update
  @post = current_blogger.blog_posts.find(params[:id])
  if @post.update_attributes(params[:post])
    redirect_to @post, notice: 'Blog post was successfully updated.'
  else
    render action: "edit"
  end
end

def destroy
  @post = current_blogger.blog_posts.find(params[:id])
  @post.destroy
  redirect_to posts_url, notice: "Blog post was successfully destroyed."
end

private

def raise_404
  # Don't include admin actions if include_admin_actions is false
  render file: "#{Rails.root}/public/404.html", status: :not_found, layout: false
end

end

end
```

All I've changed from the source so far is, I've basically created a multipart form which allows searches for locations and submits them to a locations table in the same post action. Not sure if this has anything to do with it. I can post up all this code but it's pretty lengthy. Let me know if you think this would be useful too.

Thanks a lot for all your help! Frankly, I'm stumped.

James

Answer (score 1):

Just a hunch: see if your `location` action is getting called. I just experienced a slightly different error where any calls to `redirect_to` in my controller were causing my `location` method in the same controller to get called. (Putting a `raise` at the beginning of the `location` method will quickly let you know.)

I haven't tried investigation exactly why this was happening, but renaming my `location` action fixed this (obviously, this required changing any other code that referenced that endpoint, like AJAX requests in my JavaScript). Rails magic, no doubt.